# SQL replace based on lookup table

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I replace a string based on a lookup table?

I need to replace all instances of the `Old_value` from the `Lookup_Table` anywhere in the string in `Column1` from `Table1` with `New_Value` from the `Lookup_Table`.

For example:

Table1

```
"Column1"
'The Quick BC'
'The Quick BD'
```

Lookup_Table

```
"Old_value"  | "New_Value"
'BC'         | 'Brown Cat'
'BD'         | 'Brown Dog'
```

Desired_Output

```
"Column1"
'The Quick Brown Cat'
'The Quick Brown Dog'
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Have you looked to see if theres an answer on how to replace a string in MySQL already on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious idea is to join the two tables on a LIKE condition. The `outer` join guarantees that inputs with no matches will be returned (with no changes made). However, this only works if each input string has AT MOST one substring found in the lookup table. For a more general solution, you will need a recursive query of some kind, as well as additional rules: What if both BC and BCD appear in the lookup table, and you have an input like ABCDE? Which gets priority - will you replace BC or BCD?

```
with
     Table1 ( Column1 ) as ( 
       select 'The Quick BC' from dual union all
       select 'The Quick BD' from dual
     ),
     Lookup_Table ( Old_value, New_Value) as (
       select 'BC', 'Brown Cat' from dual union all
       select 'BD', 'Brown Dog' from dual
     )
-- end of test data; the solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select column1, replace(t1.column1, lt.old_value, lt.new_value) as new_column1
from   table1 t1 left outer join lookup_table lt
                 on t1.column1 like '%' || lt.old_value || '%'
;


COLUMN1       NEW_COLUMN1
------------  -------------------
The Quick BC  The Quick Brown Cat
The Quick BD  The Quick Brown Dog
```

Comment: What do you mean by "BCD", did you mean "BD"?

Comment: No. I meant, if your lookup table had another row, BCD for "Big Canadian Donkey", and your input string was "ABCDE", which substitution would you choose? Perhaps you have a rule that you only make a substitution on a full word, not on a substring of a full word? That is the kind of "additional rules" I mentioned (note that you had NO SUCH RULE in your original question, and indeed my solution will change "ABCDE" to "ABrown CatDE"!)